# how to achieve this structure on shop page wordpress

Tags: wordpress

[image]
I want to achieve  this structure or something similar to this website
[text](https://unsaid.com/collections/bubble-collection)
or if there are any plugins that can achieve  this design pattern in WordPress.
thanks in advance

I have tried that code but it doesn't work correctly

```
enter function getProductCustom(){


$args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
        
    );
$index = 1;
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    
   echo '<div class="parrent" style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;">';
   
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        global $product;
        
        echo '<div class="'.$index.'product product" style="margin-left: 8px;margin-right: 8px; margin-top: 8px; width:25%;"><a href="'.get_permalink().'"><img src='. woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail().'</a> <h3 style="text-align: center;">'.get_the_title().'</h3> <p style="text-align: center;">'.$product->get_price_html().'</p></div>';
        if($index == 4){
        break;
        }
        $index++;
    endwhile;
    
    echo'</div>';

    $third_index = 1;
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
   echo '<div class="parrent" style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; width:100%">';
   echo'<div class="child" style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; width:50%; flex-wrap: wrap;gap: 10px; ">';
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        global $product;
        
        echo '<div class="'.$third_index.'product product" style=" width:49%;"><a href="'.get_permalink().'"><img  src='. woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail().'</a> <h3 style="text-align: center;">'.get_the_title().'</h3> <p style="text-align: center;">'.$product->get_price_html().'</p></div>';
        if($third_index ==4){
        break;
        }
        $third_index++;
    endwhile;
    echo '</div>';
    $second_index = 1;
    echo '<div class="childtwo"style="width:50%; padding-left:16px; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;" >';
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    global $product;
    
    echo '<div class="'.$second_index.'product product" style=" width:100%;"><a href="'.get_permalink().'"><img style = "width:100%; height: 100%;" src='.wp_get_attachment_url( $product->get_image_id()).'></a> </div>';
    if($second_index ==1){
    break;
    }
    $second_index++;
endwhile;
   
    
    echo'</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    wp_reset_query();

    
    echo '</div>';
```

}
add_shortcode('getProductCustom', 'getProductCustom');

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should query and count. Keep in mind will count out of stock products but wont show em. So lets say you have in first group-four 4 items but one of them is out of stock will show only 3. Just in case you get confused.

**Version 1**

```
function getProductCustom() {
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    );

    $products_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $products_query->have_posts() ) {
        $count = 0;
        $group_sizes = array(4, 5);
        $group_index = 0;

        while ( $products_query->have_posts() ) {
            $products_query->the_post();

            if ( $count === 0 ) {
                if ( $group_sizes[$group_index] === 4 ) {
                    echo '<div class="group-four">';
                } else {
                    echo '<div class="group-five">';
                }
            }

            // Display the product here
            wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
            $count++;

            if ( $count === $group_sizes[$group_index] ) {
                echo '</div>'; // Close the current group

                $group_index++;

                if ( $group_index >= count( $group_sizes ) ) {
                    $group_index = 0;
                }

                $count = 0;
            }
        }

        if ( $count > 0 ) {
            echo '</div>'; // Close the last group if there are remaining items
        }

        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
}
```

**Version 2** - here is abit different approach use any of them that you prefer

```
function getProductCustom() {
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    );
    
    $products_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    
    if ( $products_query->have_posts() ) {
        $count = 1;
        $group_count = 0;
    
        while ( $products_query->have_posts() ) {
            $products_query->the_post();
    
            if ( $count == 1 ) {
                if ( $group_count % 2 == 0 ) {
                    echo '<div class="group-four">';
                } else {
                    echo '<div class="group-five">';
                }
            }
    
            // Display the product here
            wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
    
            if ( $group_count % 2 == 0 && $count == 4 ) {
                echo '</div>';
                $count = 1;
                $group_count++;
            } elseif ( $group_count % 2 != 0 && $count == 5 ) {
                echo '</div>';
                $count = 1;
                $group_count++;
            } else {
                $count++;
            }
        }
    
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
}
```

The rest is CSS to make it look as the example.